# R (resource) file red after adding in google maps dependency

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a google maps view to my application, however every single time I attempt to add something to do with google maps it corrupts my resource files and I start getting multiple resource missing errors.

[image: Errors I receive]

I don't get these errors at all until I try to the Google Maps Dependency in my Gradle file. If I try to add a maps activity directly through the New > Google > Google Maps Activity Menu it gives me the same error.

This is a huge headache as it's the final section of an assignment, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If I remove the dependency the error goes away

Comment: can u show the code of build.gradle?

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma It seems like your answer did the trick, I entered my dependencies incorrectly, I will mark your answer as soon as possible! Thanks man! I'll also upload the code that was previously in my build for people with similar problems

Comment: yeah sure, if u faces any problem feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you added the depandancy like this?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```